# Move the cursor on another user's desktop

Tags: c#, windows

I have a program that moves the cursor over certain events, it runs from `LOCAL_SYSTEM`. Cursor movement is implemented through a standard windows tool.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
```

But since the program is launched in a “*zero*” session, the user’s cursor will not move. Reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursorpos), I saw that it seems like you can use `SetThreadDesktop` to move the cursor on a regular user. But due to ignorance of how `Windows stations` works, and lack of experience with `p/invoke`, I cannot implement this myself.

I want to understand whether my idea will work at all, and if so, then at least understand how to do it approximately.

Comment: I think you need to create a new process per window station? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services / https://jonathancrozier.com/blog/launching-a-gui-application-from-a-windows-service-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Note the above linked example assumes one user is logged in and running explorer.exe, using window station API's should allow you to enumerate login sessions more reliably. To ensure each process attaches to the intended window station (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winstation/process-connection-to-a-window-station)